# How can I delete id and name from a array of object without deleting the entire object and not leaving an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So below I have a collection in MongoDB and I want to delete **id: pa3338537**. How can delete just that ID and matching name (and not leave an empty array)?

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fc40421500bbc07cbf26c3c"
    },
    "tags": [{
        "name": "paypal",
        "id": "pa3338537"
    }, {
        "name": "donate",
        "id": "do7999655"
    }],
    "created_ts": {
        "$date": "2020-11-29T19:41:02.099Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   { _id: ObjectId("5fc40421500bbc07cbf26c3c") }, 
   { $pull: { tags: {id: "pa3338537" } } }
)
```